# How can I achieve Python `to_bytes` encoding in C#?

Tags: python, c#

I want to achieve the same result that the Python method `to_bytes` provides in C#.

When used in Python such as

```
(72).to_bytes(SIZEOF_INT,'little')
```

the method returns the value:

```
b'H\x00\x00\x00'
```

I am unable to find a method that has the same return value in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use BitConverter. Hoever that would return an array.

as in

```
int intValue;
byte[] intBytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(intValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#, the closest equivalent to `to_bytes` would be the [BitConverter.GetBytes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.getbytes) methods and the closest equivalent to `from_bytes` would be the [BitConverter.To{NumericType}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.bitconverter.toboolean) methods.

Here is how your example translates to C#:

```
int value = 72;
byte[] bytes = BitConverter.GetBytes(value);
int convertedValue = BitConverter.ToInt32(bytes);

// output: "bytes = 48 00 00 00"
Console.WriteLine($"bytes = {string.Join(" ", bytes.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")))}");

// output: "value = 72"
Console.WriteLine($"value = {convertedValue}");
```

Now the real question is: what are you trying to achieve with this conversion? Because we might be into a [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).